# Android : How to Remove all capital letters from image filenames before importing into Eclipse

Tags: android, image, file

As you know, you can't have capital letters in your image filenames that you use in your Android project (Ressource/Drawables folder).

I've got hundreds of small images (GOOG.GIF as an exemple) that I need to import into my project (I usually do a simple drag and drop from a desktop folder into Eclipse).

So here's the question :

How do I quickly change all the filenames (replace all capital letters to lower case) before importing into my project ?

So,

GOOG.GIF becomes goog.gif

AAPL.GIF becomes aapl.gif

etc.

Any quick command line solution or another tool to do just that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, I would recommend [this small script](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-filenames-lowercase) 
If you are not, I would say to have a go at google becaus eI had hundreds of answers with "change file name upercase lowercase". Like file renamer (don't know the source though, so no idea if it's safe to use.but i saw it adviced on a few blogs)

Comment: I was wondering if there was no "easy"/quick way into Eclipse itself maybe ? Thanks Sephy, will Google it further.

Comment: @Hubert why spend time hunting for a different solution if a 10 line script in pretty much any scripting language can easily do it?

Comment: I'm not using Linux (not yet, another thing I should clearly learn ;-), that's why. Still I'm validating your answer. Txs for your help.

Comment: In Eclipse, you've got either the Refactor tool (Alt+shift+R on a variable, classname, method...  or Alt+shift+T on a file name in the explorer (package or project), and then change the name, and Eclipse should rename every mention of it in your project(not always) OR you have shortcuts like ctrl+shift+x or y to go from lower to uper case and reverse. but does work only in an opened file

Answer (score 1):

I just tried "[Change Case v3.1](http://www.zealsoftstudio.com/changecase/download.html)" from Zeal SoftStudio and it worked perfectly.